# Retrieve value from a second object and display it in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-object, ampscript

Probably a newbie question... haven't been into SF for long:

In Marketing Cloud I need to make a send to a report imported from Salesforce.
I think the subscribers in the reports are all opportunity objects.

In the email, I also need to display a field from another object, called "support", where I need to pick up a phone number. 
"Support" is a separate object linked to Opportunity.

How do I write the code to pick up "phone" and display it in the email?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using AMPscript. The Function **RetrieveSalesforceObjects(1,2,3,4,5)** should be the right one for your task: [Marketing Cloud Documentation: RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/retrievesalesforceobjects/).

If you already synced this information to a data extension you can also use the **Lookup(1,2,3,4)** function for example ([Marketing Cloud Documentation: Lookup](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookup/)).

Comment: Great!
The object to retrieve values from lives only in SF.

So as key to make the lookup from - is it the contact or lead id and does that always equal subscriber key when making a send from MC?

Comment: You can define which key/field relates to the subscriberkey in your dataextension, so this isn't fixed, but usually the sfid of the object used to send (contact or lead) is used. For your lookup you can use any field you want, but using an id is the best way to go. So if available use the Id of the support object for the retrieval.

Comment: Thanks. So I am trying to make the retrieve. Can someone see if this is wrong just by a glance of it?
`
%%[ var @rs, @id
Set @id = [Opportunity Name]
Set @rs = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Opportunity", "XXTender___c", "Opportunity", "=", @id)
]%%
`
Error I keep getting:
Call to retrieve records for salesforceobject Opportunity failed! Filters did not match any field on the object specified

Comment: The Id isn't stored in the "Opportunity" field, but rather in the "Id" field, so parameter number 4 needs to be "Id". But as you select the name you should rather check against "Name", so the variable names are a bit misleading.

Comment: Hm.. this is so tricky - I am so new to SF. Does it make sense to you? 
I do not know the api name of "XX Tender" or "XX Tenders" ... so I'm stuck guessing
This is the little information I got from the customer:

In MC, they are sending to a report from SF:
Opportunities with Contact Roles report type

"XX tender" is a separate object linked to Opportunity

There is a field on "XX Tender", that's called Opportunity___c (label Opportunity). 
It's filled with reference to the opportunity.

As far as I can see or understand, the "XX Tender" is a field in an object called "XX Tenders".

Comment: Custom objects and fields in salesforce always have "__c" appended to the Name. So if you are trying to query Custom Object XXTender it would be XXTender__c, and so on. It is very hard to get it right with so little information, don't you have access to the sales/service cloud of your customer? But as my answer is the correct way to solve your problem technically and the only parts you need is the correct info of your data model, I would appreciate it if you accept my answer so others can easily see that this is the correct AMPscript function for this task.